# How to make elmah.io work well with ASP.NET Core and error handing middleware?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, elmah

Note: this question is regarding elmah.io (https://elmah.io/), the cloud based exception logging service, and not the traditional Elmah .Net library.

I'm using ASP.NET Core and have a simple exception handling middleware.

```
public class HandleExceptionMiddleware
{
    public HandleExceptionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        Next = next;
    }

    RequestDelegate Next { get; }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        try
        {
            await Next(httpContext);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(httpContext, ex);
        }
    }

    Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception ex)
    {
        var code = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

        if (ex is ArgumentException)
            code = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;

        var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { message = ex.Message });
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)code;
        return context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
    }
}
```

This middleware will return the following JSON responses depending on the exceptions that it sees:

For ArgumentException:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

{"message":""}
```

For all other exceptions:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

{"message":""}
```

I'd like elmah.io to log `500` responses and ignore `400` responses (which is the default elmah.io configuration). However, when the exception handler and elmah.io are registered in this order in Startup's Configure hook, nothing gets logged in elmah.io:

```
    app.UseElmahIo("API_KEY", new Guid("LOG_ID"));
    app.UseMiddleware<HandleExceptionMiddleware>()
```

If, however, I change the registration order to the following, everything gets logged (including 400 responses).  This makes sense as elmah.io handles the exceptions before `HandleExceptionMiddleware` gets a chance to change the response:

```
    app.UseMiddleware<HandleExceptionMiddleware>()
    app.UseElmahIo("API_KEY", new Guid("LOG_ID"));
```

What is the best way to configure these services so that elmah.io logs 500 responses and ignores 400 responses?

The only workaround I came up with is to create and register 2 exception handing middlewares instead of just 1.  One that registers before and one that registers after elmah.io.  It works, but seems a bit ugly:

```
    app.UseMiddleware<HandleInternalExceptionMiddleware>() // set 500 responses (these will have already been logged in elmah.io)
    app.UseElmahIo("API_KEY", new Guid("LOG_ID"));
    app.UseMiddleware<HandleExternalExceptionMiddleware>() // set 400 responses but ignore exceptions that should return 500 (these won't be logged in elmah.io)
```

I created a sample project here to demonstrate this behavior:
https://github.com/johnnyoshika/elmah-io-experiment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to configure elmah.io, is using behavior 2. You want to call the `UseElmahIo` method after calling other methods dealing with exceptions. This is because a lot of error handling middleware (including your `HandleExceptionMiddleware`) swallow all exceptions and convert the result to something else. In your case, `HandleExceptionMiddleware` catches all exceptions and set a new response. In this case, our middleware is never notified about the exception (as you mention as well).

We have a couple of different ways to solve this:

**Solution 1**

Call `UseElmahIo` after calling `UseMiddleware` and add a custom ignore filter to ignore the errors eventually becomming bad requests:

```cs
app.UseMiddleware<HandleExceptionMiddleware>();
app.UseElmahIo("API_KEY", new Guid("LOG_ID"), new ElmahIoSettings
{
    OnFilter = msg => msg.Type == typeof(ArgumentException).Name
});
```

The downside of this approach is, that you will need to maintain a set of similar rules in both `HandleExceptionMiddleware` and in your elmah.io config.

**Solution 2**

Call `UseElmahIo` before calling `UseMiddleware` and specify which status codes to log, even though an exception isn't thrown (swallowed by `HandleExceptionMiddleware` in this case):

```cs
app.UseElmahIo("API_KEY", new Guid("LOG_ID"), new ElmahIoSettings
{
    HandledStatusCodesToLog = new List<int> { 404, 500, ... }
});
app.UseMiddleware<HandleExceptionMiddleware>();
```

The downside if this approach is, that you will need to specify all status codes manually and that the information from the actual exception thrown, isn't available on elmah.io. The reason for this again is, that `HandleExceptionMiddleware` make it impossible for elmah.io to see that an exception were thrown.

I personally prefer solution 1, since that makes sure that all exceptions are catched, including information like stacktrace and the exception type.

Comment: Great answer! I learned quite a few things.  I had thought that because elmah.io logs 500 responses by default, that I didn't have to add 500 to the `HandledStatusCodesToLog` list.  I've now learned that the behavior is different when 500 is in that list.  Like you said, solution 2 is definitely not great b/c the stack trace won't be logged.  Solution 1 is better and it will solve my problem, but I think I'm going to stick with the 2 middleware approach because this way, I don't need to maintain the same rules in 2 places.